# NestJS problem mocking axios obersvable response

Tags: unit-testing, axios, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I am having problems mocking a nestjs/axios call in a unit test.

I have tried to mock the implementation but it always times out which means that it is not working correctly

```js
jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => of(result))

const response: CustomerDetail =  await client.getCustomerDetails('1');
expect(response).toBeDefined();
```

Below is a sample of the code that i am trying to test. Note: I am using lastValueFrom to convert the observable to a promise.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomerDetailsClient {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  async getCustomerDetails(customerId: string): Promise < CustomerDetail > {

    let customerDetails: Promise < CustomerDetail > = null;

    try {
      customerDetails = await lastValueFrom(this.httpService.get(`localhost:80/customers/${customerId}/details`)
        .pipe(
          map((response) => {
            return response.data
          }),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException('A system error occurred');
    }

    return customerDetails;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show what your `result` is, and what's the current outcome of your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the following code

```js
const response: Promise<CustomerDetail> =  client.getCustomerDetails('1');
const customerDetail: CustomerDetail = await response;
expect(response).toBeDefined();
```